# FastCV and Windows Phone 8 (C#)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, computer-vision

I want to build a Windows Phone 8 (C#) application with Qualcommm's FastCV. It's very simple with Android, about I have problems with Windows Phone because there isn't any documentation about it.

After installation [FastCV SDK v1.5 for Windows Phone](https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/add-advanced-features/computer-vision-fastcv/tools-and-resources), I have a header file (fastcv.h) and a .lib file (libfastcvnative.wp63.lib). How can I use/refer the both C++ files in VS 2012/2013? Are there also a tool like CDT in Eclipse?

At [Qualcomm's Dev-Forum](https://developer.qualcomm.com/forum/qdn-forums/add-advanced-features/computer-vision-fastcv/27439) there is a solution, but I cannot understand it.

Another question: Are there others computer vision (object detection, text recognition ..) for windows phone 8 - maybe with a better documentation?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't refer to the header and lib file from your C# project.  You need a compiled library and you can then use that in your C# project (though I'd have to research how exactly to do that, as I've never had need to before).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across over **[this](http://fcvnet.codeplex.com/)** CodePlex project. It seems to be doing what you need. If it does not work, you could try the approach below.

One problem is that C# is managed code, while FastCV library is probably native code.

So you would need a wrapper that "forwards" the FastCV functions you intend to use. Native Code and Manged C++ interoperability is more easy to have as you can have managed code and native code even in the same file. See **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173185.aspx)** for more details.

So you need to make a manged C++ library, load it as an assembly from your C# project and consume it from there. The C++ managed library will just call the native FastCV functions.

> Are there others computer vision (object detection, text recognition
>   ..) for windows phone 8 - maybe with a better documentation?

Yes. **You can have OpenCV for Windows 8 / 8.1.** Check **[here](http://msopentech.com/blog/2014/08/20/opencv-support-for-windows-universal-apps-now-available-on-github/)** for more information. It's not guaranteed to be optimized better than FastCV but I have a feeling that it's much more complete than FastCV functions. I would go with OpenCV before FastCV.

Comment: Thanks! OpenCV for Windows 8 / 8.1 looks great. I'll post my work here.